# How to configure VS Code to use Cmder?

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, terminal, cmder

I'm using `VS code` as my `IDE` for `Python` (anaconda environment). So I configured `cmder` as my terminal and I tried to test a simple `print` statement by clicking on the run button (green triangle). I got the following error:

[image]

My `JSON` settings looks like this:

```
   {
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "Cmder.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "CMDER_ROOT": "C:\\Users\\EK\\Cmder.exe"
    },
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "/k",
        "%CMDER_ROOT%\\vendor\\bin\\vscode_init.Cmder"
    ],
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe",
    "atomKeymap.promptV3Features": true,
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "terminal.background": "#1D2021",
        "terminal.foreground": "#09c0f8",
        "terminalCursor.background": "#A89984",
        "terminalCursor.foreground": "#A89984",
        "terminal.ansiBlack": "#1D2021",
        "terminal.ansiBlue": "#0D6678",
        "terminal.ansiBrightBlack": "#665C54",
        "terminal.ansiBrightBlue": "#0D6678",
        "terminal.ansiBrightCyan": "#8BA59B",
        "terminal.ansiBrightGreen": "#95C085",
        "terminal.ansiBrightMagenta": "#8F4673",
        "terminal.ansiBrightRed": "#FB543F",
        "terminal.ansiBrightWhite": "#FDF4C1",
        "terminal.ansiBrightYellow": "#FAC03B",
        "terminal.ansiCyan": "#fbfdfc",
        "terminal.ansiGreen": "#95C085",
        "terminal.ansiMagenta": "#8F4673",
        "terminal.ansiRed": "#FB543F",
        "terminal.ansiWhite": "#A89984",
        "terminal.ansiYellow": "#FAC03B"
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Dimmed",
    "workbench.editor.decorations.colors": true,
    "workbench.preferredHighContrastColorTheme": "Visual Studio Light",
    "python.formatting.provider": "none",
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.linux": "",
    "terminal.integrated.scrollback": 100000,
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ],
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {}
}
```

I have no clue why things are going wrong? Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the absolute path of the executable file of "cmder", and use this path in "settings.json":

[image]

"settings.json":

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "..:\\cmder\\Cmder.exe",
```

Run:

[image]

In addition, please check whether the "cmder" terminal can be used outside of VS Code.

Reference: [Integrated Terminal in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows).

Comment: I want to use `cmder` as an integrated terminal in VS code. I don't want a new terminal window to be popped up.

Comment: @TangerCity -Currently, VS Code does not support embedding custom terminals inside it. Please refer to it: [Is it possible to integrate the terminal that comes with the system into VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115659).

Comment: Is it possible to private chat?

Comment: @TangerCity -Do you have any questions? We can discuss it here and the record will help others in need.